# How to change the contents After submitting the Apps in the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have submitted my apps into the AppStore and it's in AppStore now. Now client wants to made some changes on the apps, like Description, Email, Supporting URL, Client Name and Seller Name.

Note:

I know it's possible to change the description name, Email Address and Supporting URL's. Is possible to change the client Name in the Apps? (For Eg: PugalDevan LLC. want to change Pugal LLC.) I donno how can i proceed to next. But i know, if i resubmit to my apps into the appstore again, then the changes are made. If i resubmit my apps, then the version should be changed.So my client insist to me, to do those changes. How can i contact to apple help team  and please give me a apple supporting team mail id. Please guide me.

Thanks.

Regards,

Pugal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client wants to change the seller name, they will have to enroll in a new developer account, pay another $99, and submit the app using that new account, with a new slightly different app name.  There is no way to change the seller name of the old app (unless you have legal proof that the entire seller corporation was acquired by another.)

The other data can be changed by submitting an update.

Comment: +1, @hotpaw2, Thanks for the reply. Now i am clear. So how can i delete or revoke my old apps from the AppStore. Is this possible to delete my apps from the AppStore. Thanks.

Comment: You can uncheck all countries in availability, or set the for-sale date to 2013 in iTunes connect, or delete the app.

Answer (score 4):

You have to release an updated version of the app. If all that changes is the branding and support text, etc, then that's all that changes - you can't escape from having to release an update.

I suspect you're worried that not all users will download the new update, and that they will continue to see the wrong branding or whatever. But there is no way to force an update or to change contents of an existing app.

Comment: +1, Thanks for your reply. If i submit to the next version of my apps, should i change the client(company) name?.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to do this once, and even contacting Apple didn't solved my problem, only releasing a new version of the App enabled me to change the data.

Answer (score 1):

You remember the time when you filled in the seller name? It said something like "You cannot change this later, so please double check if everything is correct"

You can't change the name of the seller. It is bundled with your account. Every app you add to your account will be sold under the developer name you entered when you filled in the information for your first app.

And from past experience I can tell you to change the developer name you have to delete the current account, and open a new one. But this was more than a year ago, and the account had no apps live, so maybe apple is willing to do the changes for you.

There is a huge `Contact Us` link on the itunes connect homepage.

Comment: funny that you say this after I saw that you deleted your comment and I decided to delete mine too ^^